# Sharepoint 2013 foundation custom css

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-foundation, css

I am having trouble adding my custom css file work in Sharepoint 2013 foundation. I added a link tag in both v4.master and seattle master pages but to no avail. I thought it would be straight forward or as easy as Sharepoint 2010.

Could you help explain this to me? Also I can't find the _layouts folder that holds the core15.css file.

Or is there a link that I can go to with tutorials and etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layouts folder can be found at the following location

```
%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS
```

The COREV15.CSS file can be found at

```
%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES
```

Were 1033 is the installed language folder.

You can register your CSS for example below the default corev15.css like this

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/_layouts/15/styles/<youre css file here>" runat="server" />
```

There is one more property of a SharePoint site called [AlternateCssUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.alternatecssurl.aspx). You would use this property if you don’t want to create a MasterPage or a Theme, but just apply a skin on the SharePoint default look – by specifying a value for this property, you make SharePoint include your style sheet in its pages.

Comment: Thank you Remko for replying. My follow up question is where  exactly would I put this code: <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/_layouts/15/styles/<youre css file here>" runat="server" />. Is it under the v4.master?

Comment: It depends which master you use. For css only you can also look at setting SPWeb.AlternateCssUrl. Added some additional info to the answer.

Comment: Oh, I understand. If I link it in one master page (seattle.master) it will work for all. Thank you.